# Tab autocompletion in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I'm beginner in Maxima. I'm sorry if I ask a basic and easy question.

The candidate of functions/variables will be shown in maxima prompt when  TAB key is pressed.

for example,

```
(%i1) desc.. 
/*--> [TAB] is pressed. */
(%i1) DESCRIBE
/*Automatically the word is completed.*/
```

But "DESCRIBE" with capital letters isn't recognized by Maxima because Maxima is case-sensitive system. The command completion  with lower-case letter is more preferable for me. Is there way to change the behavior in Maxima?

**Environment & Software version**

---

Maxima version: "5.32.1"

Host type: "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that is the autocompletion feature of the underlying Lisp system; Maxima itself does not have an autocompletion feature. Common Lisp has a very strange convention for symbol names; by default, symbol names are case insensitive, but the canonical name is uppercase. So `foo`, `Foo`, and `FOO` are all recognized as the same symbol which has the canonical name `FOO`. It doesn't matter to the Maxima user, but anyway that's why autocompletion yields `DESCRIBE` (a Lisp symbol) instead of `describe`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use wxMaxima as a front end that offers its own (hopefully bug-free ;-) ) autocompletion that is triggered by Ctrl+Tab or Ctrl+Space.